# fetching data from multiple table using subquery

Tags: sql

I have two tables

TABLE : EMPLOYEE

```
EMP_ID  EMP_NAME    EMP_TYPE
1   Shwetha           1
2   Raj               1
3   Mani              1
4   Sita              2
5   Rani              3
6   Guna              2
```

TABLE : EMPMAP

```
MAP_ID (PK) EMP_ID  EMPMAP_ID
1             1 4
2             4 5
3             1 6
```

In 2nd table it shows emp 4 is under 1, and 4 is under 5 and again 6 is under 1

I want to fetch employees who are working under a particular employee. For example, I want details of employees 4 and 5 if I pass empid 1 to the query and details of 5 if I want for 4.

Can anyone tell me how can I write the query for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select e.*
from EMPMAP map
join EMPLOYEE e on e.EMP_ID = map.EMPMAP_ID
where map.EMP_ID = @empId
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought the requirement was to get all subordinates, all levels down - but that's not the original question....

Comment: @marc_s, +1 to your answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL Server 2005 or newer, or any other database that supports recursive CTE (Common Table Expression), you can write a recursive CTE like this, if you need all levels of subordinates under a given employee (not just the immediate next-level down subordinates):

```
DECLARE @StartEmpID INT = 1

;WITH EmployeeHierarchy AS
(
    SELECT 
       e.EmpID, e.EmpName, e.EmpType, 0 AS 'Level', NULL AS 'Supervisor ID'
    FROM dbo.Employee e
    WHERE e.EmpID = @StartEmpID

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
       e.EmpID, e.EmpName, e.EmpType, Level + 1 AS 'Level', map.emp_id 
    FROM dbo.Employee e
    INNER JOIN dbo.EmpMap map ON e.EmpID = map.empmap_id
    INNER JOIN EmployeeHierarchy eh ON map.emp_id = eh.EmpID
)
SELECT * 
FROM EmployeeHierarchy
```

This will generate a recursive listing of all employees down from the one defined by the `@StartEmpID` - over several levels.

In your case, you'd get an output something like this:

```
EmpID   EmpName EmpType Level   Supervisor ID
 1      Shwetha       1       0        NULL
 4      Sita          2       1         1
 6      Guna          2       1         1
 5      Rani          3       2         4
```

Answer (score 0):

first, i think you want to say, you want details of employees 4 and 6 (NOT 4 and 5) if you pass emp_id 1.
And sql for this is:

```
SELECT E.EMP_NAME, E.EMP_TYPE 
FROM EMPLOYEE E INNER JOIN EMPMAP EM ON E.EMP_ID = EM.EMPMAP_ID 
WHERE EM.EMP_ID = 1
```